# laravel-ajax response is null

Tags: ajax, laravel

I added this:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Its ajax area:

```
$.ajax({
     url: '{{ route('fav.add') }}',
     headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
     },
     type: 'POST',
     data: {id},
     dataType: 'text',
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
     success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
     }
})
```

It's my controller:

```
public function addFav(Request $request) {
    return $request->id;
}
```

I'm not reaching id.

If i change my controller like this:

```
public function addFav(Request $request) {
     return "test";
}
```

There is no problem, i'm reaching the test text,  but when i try to reach id I can not reach. How to fix it? If you help me i will be glad.

Comment: data: {id}, but you have not shown where id is declared

Comment: Might just be a typo; `data: { id: 1 }` would send `1` as the ID for example. Also, for AJAX requests, use `return response()->json(['id' => $request->id]);`

Comment: Its turning also "id: null",  as well as i declared id in the function -- function fav(id) { .......  }   like this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. The problem is that 2 rows. I deleted them and it worked fine.

```js
contentType: false,
processData: false,
```